# Microsoft interop supported files

Tags: c#, interop

I searched a lot but I was unable to find what excel files are supported by Microsoft Interop. I want to make a full 97-2013 excel support on a project and I don't know if Inrerop can support old files. Can anyone to help me ?
Thanks!

Comment: The interops are just interface to permit the .NET CLR to be able to communicate to the COM DLL. if you DLL is Office 2010 then it can open an file Excel 2010 can. as simple as that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be asking the wrong question (which is probably why you did not find this information online).

Interop is just an interface layer to the installed version of Office. If the Excel version installed supports the files you are interested in, it does so as well when remote-controlled through interop. If it doesn't, interop won't add this functionality.

Comment: @StefiPallo: It's even worse: If you want to deploy your application, it depends on *the customer's* version of Office. Therefore, it might make sense to use a third-party Excel library to manipulate Excel files instead of Interop.

Comment: Using excel is always the worst for programmers. as it's not reliable because of format. BUT, you can rely on ADO to connect to excel and query like database. this would work if you only require to read/edit an existing file. Otherwise like @Heinzi said you will need third party if you need creation and if you want to deploy to customer, you will need tool such as Spreadsheet Gear in this case.